# Finding the smallest distance between xyz

Tags: c++, position, distance

Hi so okay put it this way.
We have 12 players well what I want to do is find the closest one.

I've written some code below; two versions of my attempt (trust me theirs been a lot more, could of written a bible by now)

```
/*int client::closestEnemy()
{
    for(u32 i = 0; i<12; i++)
    {
        DbgPrint("i: %i\n", i);
        u32 index = 0;
        if(!p[i].exist() || !p[i].alive() || p[i].team() == 3 || i == s.index) 
                 continue;

        for(u32 o = 0; o<12; o++) 
                 if(vec.distance(*pos(), *p[i].pos()) <= vec.distance(*pos(), *p[o].pos()) || vec.distance(*pos(), *p[i].pos()) == vec.distance(*pos(), *p[o].pos()))
                       index++;
        DbgPrint("PLAYER %s INDEX = %i\n", p[i].readName(), index);

        if(index>10)  
            return i;

        index = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}*/


int client::closestEnemy()
{
    float distacnes[11] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    u32 index = 0;
    for(u32 i = 0; i<12; i++)
        if(p[i].exist() || p[i].alive() || p[i].team() != 3 || i != s.index) 
             distacnes[i] = vec.distance(*pos(), *p[i].pos()); 
        else 
             continue;

    for(u32 i = 0; i<12; i++) 
         if(distacnes[i]<distacnes[i+1]) 
             index++;

    DbgPrint("Score = %i\n", index);

    if(index>11) 
        return index;

    return -1;
}
```

What I am doing is simply increment index by 1 when ever another clients distance is larger then mine.

Now the first one is best bet but sometimes does not create a high enough index which makes zero sense because at least one client has to have a smaller distance then everyone else.

Comment: Have you verified that this lengthy condition in the first loop (in either version) is doing what you want it to do? From your description of the problem I have no idea why half of these conditions exist, perhaps I just lack context.

Comment: When you step through, does `distances` contain the correct value? If so, just iterate through the list storing a smallest value (which you start at infinity so first one is always smallest) and the index it corresponds to. Sorry if I've missed the point some what

Comment: Yeah sorry I was very dull here. My statments okay and distance is too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some indentation would help, I guess.
Then, there's no need to store all distances. You can keep track of the minimum distance encountered so far, like this:

```
int client::closestEnemy()
{
    int index = -1;
    float minDistance;
    for(u32 i = 0; i<12; i++) {
        if(p[i].exist() || p[i].alive() || p[i].team() != 3 || i != s.index) {
            float distance = vec.distance(*pos(), *p[i].pos());
            if (index == -1 || distance < minDistance) {
                index = i;
                minDistance = distance;
            }
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Very nice job Yannick. These type of things drive me crazy and breaks my brain. Storing all the distances in my second example was rather stupid but was for trial and error testing. This looks VERY hoping and clean too :) thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I must say, I didn't test this yet, but this looks the most natural way to fix it, to me... (Although there probably is a more subtle approach to the `index == -1` construction)

Comment: To avoid the index=-1 issue, you can set minDistance to be some sufficiently large value ideally, the biggest float (eg something like `std::numeric_limits<float>::max();`

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the C++ way to get +inf.
But then again, if you want to return -1 if none was found, the solution might be suitable as it is now...

Comment: if(p[i].exist() && i != s.index) { im so confused of how this is still returning my index.

Comment: Hey man! your code works great. Take a load of this shit. I just played my self so hard. Okay so I have a G15 Logitech keyboard with my G6 key programmed to (SHIFT + CONTROL + B) for compile, well that g-key broke and this entire time my project hasnt even been updating / building.

Comment: What do you mean?
What this thing does is saying: 1. Haven't found a minimum yet; 2. Loop over all other players; 2.1. Check if the player matches the prerequisites of your original code; 2.2. If so, and if there is no current minimum, or the distance is smaller than the current minimum distance, update the current minimum distance and its matching index; 3. Return the index found (if the condition of p[i] was never matched, -1 will be returned, just as you did)